Confusion regarding magnitude of units in Electronics
I'm currently studying electronics by myself using the book of Introduction to Electronics, fifth edition, by Earl D. Gates and have reached the topic of Power, in it there's a problem where I have to calculate a resistor in a parallel circuit and among the given units are these:
Pr1 = 18mW
Ir1 = 1.5mA
E1 = ?
in order to calculate the voltage I used the formula of P = I * E and rearranged it as E = P/I then substituted the units E = 18mW/1.5mA = 12mV HOWEVER the answer in the book converted the watts and amperes from mW and mA to W and A so that E = P/I was instead E = 0.018W/0.0015A = 12V which doesn't make sense to me because if 18mW/1.5mA = 0.018W/0.0015A the solution to this should be equal but we instead get 12mV = 12 V which isn't true. Am I doing something wrong? am I not understanding something about units here?

Dividing by 1/1000 (milli) is the same as multiplying by 1000.

That reminds me of the proposal that if Jeff Bezos has 200 billion and there a 8 billion people on the planet, he can give everyone 1 billion and still has 192 billion.

Yes, you misunderstood the meaning of unit-prefixes.
The milli prefix is by definition identical to a factor of $0.001$.
Therefore, in the fraction  you can cancel them just like you can cancel normal numbers.
$$\frac{18\text{ mW}}{1.5\text{ mA}}
=\frac{18\cdot 0.001\text{ W}}{1.5\cdot 0.001\text{ A}}
=\frac{18\text{ W}}{1.5\text{ A}}
=12\text{ V}$$
